# Need help on jdbcTemplates in Spring MVC3

Tags: spring

I am  working on Spring MVC3, I am thinking to use JDBCTemplates for the database interaction.

Can anybody help how to write the context.xml file and the java code to access it for connecting.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `DataSource` bean first

ex: using springs [DriverManagerDataSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html).

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>${jdbc.driverClassName}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${jdbc.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then create `JdbcTemplate` bean using the dataSource.

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I already wtote this... But it is giving an error saying that the file not found error for context.xml... Can you pls tell me where do i have to keep that file

Comment: How are you creating the `applicationContext` and where did you place the `context.xml` file? Can you share the code and exception.

Comment: combine the above 2 answers and then you get what you want, it's very easy. so glad that more guys starting to use spring mvc.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at com.cogni.co.DBHelper.main(DBHelper.java:24)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: I kept the context.xml in WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml and i mensioned in web.xml also about this.. even then the error is coming.. :(

Comment: What is the configurationLocation value passed in web.xml?

Comment: <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

Comment: i kept the applicationContext.xml also in the same location as mentioned in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the contextConfigLocation parameter in web.xml for spring to find its context files. For example, add the following line in your WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and put your content.xml in WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring folder.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html)? It has following examples :

**1. XML Approach :**

Code :

```
public class JdbcCorporateEventDao implements CorporateEventDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    // JDBC-backed implementations of the methods on the CorporateEventDao follow...
}
```

XML Config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="corporateEventDao" class="com.example.JdbcCorporateEventDao">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties"/>

</beans>
```

**2. Annotation Approach :**

```
@Repository
public class JdbcCorporateEventDao implements CorporateEventDao {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    // JDBC-backed implementations of the methods on the CorporateEventDao follow...
}
```

**Datasource Configuration :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.docs.test" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties"/>

</beans>
```